# Start NodeJS application using pm2 and bytenode

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I am converting my NodeJS code to V8 bytecode using this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytenode). I have installed it locally and when try to execute the command `./node_modules/bytenode/cli.js index.jsc` it works and for starting using pm2 if I install the module globally and execute the command `pm2 start "bytenode index.jsc"` then also it works. But the problem I am facing is when I try to start with pm2 using the local installation of bytenode as I want to avoid the global installation of the same. I want to achieve something like this `pm2 start "./node_modules/bytenode/cli.js index.jsc"` but could not get it to work any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** If I define `./node_modules/bytenode/cli.js index.jsc` in the `package.json` start command and execute `pm2 start "npm run start"` it works, but I want to achieve the same from command line without using the `npm run` command.

**Update:** I even tried defining the command `"./node_modules/bytenode/cli.js index.jsc"` in the script key by generating the `ecosystem.config.js` and running `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` but still no success.

Comment: have you tried command: pm2 start index.jsc by entering into your projects directory.

Comment: Yes but this will not work as it is converted to V8 bytecode and will need the interpreter for the same to execute for which will need to use bytenode to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

Update ***launcher.js*** file with below lines:

```
require('bytenode');
require('./index.jsc');
```

And then you need to ***run launcher.js with pm2***:

```
pm2 start launcher.js
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: I did try that but without any success

Comment: hey! I would like you to go through a git repo https://github.com/florian-kittel/nodejs-webpack-bytenode-demo and try it out at your end so that you can simplify your personal application :)